Diskspace Report HTML Text Color Output
I'm trying to modify the text color output of this awesome script.
I just want the text for Critical Red background cells to be white.
What am I doing wrong here?
If I get flamed for posting huge glob of code, I totally understand.
I've tried earnestly to update this but I'm horrific at coding.
 
# Set your warning and critical thresholds 
$percentWarning = 90; #wildly increased for testing critical threshold
$percentCritcal = 95; #wildly increased for testing
 
 
# REPORT PROPERTIES 
 # Path to the report 
  $reportPath = "C:\scripts\diskspace\Report\"; 
 
 # Report name 
  $reportName = "DiskSpaceRpt_$(get-date -format ddMMyyyy).html"; 
 
# Path and Report name together 
$diskReport = $reportPath + $reportName 
 
#Set colors for table cell backgrounds 
$redColor = "#FF0000" 
$orangeColor = "#FBB917" 
$FontColor = "#000000"
$fontcolorwhite = "#FFFFFF"

 
# Count if any computers have low disk space.  Do not send report if less than 1. 
$i = 0; 
 
# Get computer list to check disk space 
$computers = Get-Content "C:\scripts\diskspace\servers.txt"; 
$datetime = Get-Date -Format "MM-dd-yyyy_HHmmss"; 
 
# Remove the report if it has already been run today so it does not append to the existing report 
If (Test-Path $diskReport) 
    { 
        Remove-Item $diskReport 
    } 
 
# Cleanup old files.. 
$Daysback = "-7" 
$CurrentDate = Get-Date; 
$DateToDelete = $CurrentDate.AddDays($Daysback); 
Get-ChildItem $reportPath | Where-Object { $_.LastWriteTime -lt $DatetoDelete } | Remove-Item; 
 
# Create and write HTML Header of report 
$titleDate = get-date -uformat "%m-%d-%Y - %A" 
$header = " 
  <html> 
  <head> 
  <meta http-equiv='Content-Type' content='text/html; charset=iso-8859-1'> 
  <title>DiskSpace Report</title> 
  <STYLE TYPE='text/css'> 
  <!-- 
  td { 
   font-family: Tahoma; 
   font-size: 11px; 
   border-top: 1px solid #999999; 
   border-right: 1px solid #999999; 
   border-bottom: 1px solid #999999; 
   border-left: 1px solid #999999; 
   padding-top: 0px; 
   padding-right: 0px; 
   padding-bottom: 0px; 
   padding-left: 0px; 
  } 
  body { 
   margin-left: 5px; 
   margin-top: 5px; 
   margin-right: 0px; 
   margin-bottom: 10px; 
   table { 
   border: thin solid #000000; 
  } 
  --> 
  </style> 
  </head> 
  <body> 
  <table width='100%'> 
  <tr bgcolor='#CCCCCC'> 
  <td colspan='7' height='25' align='center'> 
  <font face='tahoma' color='#003399' size='4'><strong>ghostinthewires Internal DiskSpace Report for $titledate</strong></font> 
  </td> 
  </tr> 
  </table> 
" 
 Add-Content $diskReport $header 
 
# Create and write Table header for report 
 $tableHeader = " 
 <table width='100%'><tbody> 
 <tr bgcolor=#CCCCCC> 
    <td width='10%' align='center'>Server</td> 
 <td width='5%' align='center'>Drive</td> 
 <td width='15%' align='center'>Drive Label</td> 
 <td width='10%' align='center'>Total Capacity(GB)</td> 
 <td width='10%' align='center'>Used Capacity(GB)</td> 
 <td width='10%' align='center'>Free Space(GB)</td> 
 <td width='5%' align='center'>Freespace %</td> 
 </tr> 
" 
Add-Content $diskReport $tableHeader 
  
# Start processing disk space reports against a list of servers 
  foreach($computer in $computers) 
 {  
 $disks = Get-WmiObject -ComputerName $computer -Class Win32_LogicalDisk -Filter "DriveType = 3" 
 $computer = $computer.toupper() 
  foreach($disk in $disks) 
 {         
  $deviceID = $disk.DeviceID; 
        $volName = $disk.VolumeName; 
  [float]$size = $disk.Size; 
  [float]$freespace = $disk.FreeSpace;  
  $percentFree = [Math]::Round(($freespace / $size) * 100, 2); 
  $sizeGB = [Math]::Round($size / 1073741824, 2); 
  $freeSpaceGB = [Math]::Round($freespace / 1073741824, 2); 
        $usedSpaceGB = $sizeGB - $freeSpaceGB; 
        $color = $whiteColor; 
        $fontcolor = $FontColorBlack
 
# Set background color to Orange if just a warning 
 if($percentFree -lt $percentWarning)       
  { 
    $color = $orangeColor  
 
# Set background color to Orange if space is Critical 
      if($percentFree -lt $percentCritcal) 
        { 
        $color = $redColor
        $fontcolor = $fontcolorwhite
       }         
  
 # Create table data rows  
    $dataRow = " 
  <tr> 
        <td width='10%'>$computer</td> 
  <td width='5%' align='center'>$deviceID</td> 
  <td width='15%' >$volName</td> 
  <td width='10%' align='center'>$sizeGB</td> 
  <td width='10%' align='center'>$usedSpaceGB</td> 
  <td width='10%' align='center'>$freeSpaceGB</td> 
  <td width='5%' font face='tahoma' font color=`'$FontColor`' size='4' bgcolor=`'$color`' align='center'>$percentFree</td> 
  </tr> 
" 
Add-Content $diskReport $dataRow; 
Write-Host -ForegroundColor DarkYellow "$computer $deviceID percentage free space = $percentFree"; 
    $i++   
  } 
 } 
} 
 
# Create table at end of report showing legend of colors for the critical and warning 
 $tableDescription = " 
 </table><br><table width='20%'> 
 <tr bgcolor='White'> 
    <td width='10%' align='center' bgcolor='#FBB917'>Warning less than 15% free space</td> 
 <td width='10%' align='center' bgcolor='#FF0000'>Critical less than 10% free space</td> 
 </tr> 
" 
  Add-Content $diskReport $tableDescription 
 Add-Content $diskReport "</body></html>" 
 


Setting #FontColor variables for text color to dynamically change output.

NEW ANSWER 2024-12-18
I basically rewrote half the code lol.
Now it's quite commented on why and how.
It should be easy to understand.
## mark my specific comments.
I stand my opinion that making the HTML template its own file would make this script much easier on eyes.
# Set your warning and critical thresholds 
$percentWarning = 90; #wildly increased for testing critical threshold
$percentCritcal = 95; #wildly increased for testing


# REPORT PROPERTIES 
# Path to the report 
$reportPath = 'C:\scripts\diskspace\Report\' 

## Renamed for clarity of content.   
## Also it's now a DateTime object so you can use it instead of calling the function multiple times.   
$CurrentDate = Get-Date #-Format 'MM-dd-yyyy_HHmmss' 



# Report name 
## Restructured to use the variable instead of calling again the cmdlet.  
$reportName = 'DiskSpaceRpt_{0}.html' -f $CurrentDate.ToString('ddMMyyy')

# Path and Report name together 
## Renamed for clarity of content.   
## Used 
$DiskReportPath = Join-Path -Path $reportPath -ChildPath $reportName 

## If the file doesn't exist, creates it(and its directory ).  
## If the file does exist, overwrites it.  
## In both cases, save the link to the file as a FileInfo object to reuse it.   
$DiskReportFile = New-Item -ItemType File -Path $DiskReportPath -Force


# Count if any computers have low disk space.  Do not send report if less than 1. 
## Removed because we can use a calculated value later
# $NumberLowSpaceComputers = 0 

# Get computer list to check disk space   
## Renamed for clarity of content.   
## Also force-casted into a String Array, also for clarity.   
[string[]]$ComputersArray = Get-Content 'C:\scripts\diskspace\servers.txt' 




# Cleanup old files.. 
$Daysback = '-7' 
$DateToDelete = $CurrentDate.AddDays($Daysback) 
## Evaluate adding the parameters -File to Get-ChildItem if you are not intersted in deleting the directories.  
## If you ARE interested in deleting the directories, I suggest to add the parameter -Recourse to Remove-Item.   
## If you are making a simple comparison of a property in Where-Object, the scriptblock is useless.  
Get-ChildItem $reportPath | Where-Object -Property LastWriteTime -LT $DatetoDelete | Remove-Item 

# Create and write HTML Header of report 
## Using the already existing variable instead of calling Get-Date AGAIN.  
## Why was it using the Unix Format to format it though?   
$titleDate = $CurrentDate.ToString('MM-dd-yyyy - dddd')


<#
        Here a longer comment. Basically: most of the page is static. The only parts
        changing are the date in the title and the lines of the disks. So I made a
        Template in 3 parts:   
            #   The main HTML.   
            #   A template for the disk rows.   
            #   The CSS, because its curly brackets don't play well with templates
                and it's also complex enough it's better to keep it separated for
                easier reading.   



        Anyway: this makes writing the HTML+CSS much easier, but I suggest
        evaluating moving the template in its own files to dynamically    load by
        Get-Content if this becomes complex enough.  

        Especially because I pretty much rewrote it all to be HTML5-compliant.  
        Most properties now are managed by CSS.   
        More about them in the CSS variable, commented to be read even after being
        compiled.

    #>
$Css = '
    /* This will be the base value for all Table Rows */
    tr {
        background-color: #cccccc;
    }

    /* This will be the base value for all Table Cells, both Header Cells<TH> and Data Cells<TD> */
    td, th {
        width: 10%;
        text-align: center;
    }

    /* This will be the base value for all Table Header Cells<TH> */
    /* Its values combine with those set in the previous declaration */
    /* In case of overlapping property settings, the successive overrides the previous */
    th {
        font-family: Tahoma, sans-serif;
        font-weight: bold;
        color: #003399;
    }

    /* This will affect Table Header Cells with the "Main" class */
    th.main {
        width: 100%;
        font-size: larger;
    }

    /* This will affect ANY element with the "Warning" class */
    .Warning {
        background-color: #FBB917;
    }

    /* This will affect ANY element with the "Critical" class */
    .Critical {
        background-color: #ff0000;
        color: #ffffff;
    }


    /* This will affect Table Data Cells that are inside Table Rows that are inside the Table Footer */
    tfoot tr {
        background-color: #ffffff;
    }

    /* This will affect ANY element with the "Warning" class inside the Table Footer<TFOOT> element */
    tfoot .Warning {
        width: 10%;
        color: unset;
    }

    /* This will affect ANY element with the "Warning" class inside the Table Footer<TFOOT> element */
    tfoot .Critical {
        width: 10%;
        color: unset;
    }

    /* This will affect ANY element with the "NoCenter" class */
    .NoCenter {
        /* This specifically resets the text alignment to the default */
        text-align: unset;
    }



    /* This will affect ANY element with the "FivePercent" class */
    .FivePercent {
        width: 5%;
    }

    /* This will affect ANY element with the "FifteenPercent" class */
    .FifteenPercent {
        width: 15%;
    }

    '


$HtmlTemplate = " 
    <!doctype html>
    <html lang='en'>

    <head>
        <meta http-equiv='Content-Type' content='text/html; charset=utf-8'>
        <title>DiskSpace Report ({0} )</title>
        <STYLE>
        {1}
        </style>
    </head>

    <body>
        <table>
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th colspan='7' class='main'> ghostinthewires Internal DiskSpace Report for {0} </th>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <th>Server</th>
                    <th class='FivePercent'>Drive</th>
                    <th class='FifteenPercent'>Drive Label</th>
                    <th>Total Capacity(GB)</th>
                    <th>Used Capacity(GB)</th>
                    <th>Free Space(GB)</th>
                    <th class='FivePercent'>Freespace %</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
    {2}
            </tbody> 
            <tfoot>
                <tr> 
                    <td class='Warning'>Warning less than 15% free space</td> 
                    <td class='Critical'>Critical less than 10% free space</td> 
                    <td colspan='5'></td>
                </tr> 
        </tfoot>
        </table>
    </body>
    </html>
    " 

$TableRowTemplate = " 
                <tr> 
                    <td >{0}</td> 
                    <td class='FivePercent' >{1}</td> 
                    <td  class='FifteenPercent NoCenter'>{2}</td> 
                    <td  >{3:n2}</td> 
                    <td  >{4:n2}</td> 
                    <td  >{5:n2}</td> 
                    <td class='FivePercent {6}' >{7}</td> 
                </tr> 
    "




# Start processing disk space reports against a list of servers 
## I wrote it so every Success Stream output will be added to the $HtmlTableRowArray array.  
## And the Success Stream is obviously a string formatted from $TableRowTemplate.   
## It also means you don't need a dedicated variable to keep track of how many disks have issues: 
## you can simply use the .Count property of $HtmlTableRowArray.   
$HtmlTableRowArray = foreach ($computer in $ComputersArray) {  
    ## Using Get-CimInstance because the Wmi cmdlets are obsolete.   
    $disks = Get-CimInstance -ComputerName $computer -Class Win32_LogicalDisk -Filter 'DriveType = 3' 
        
    ## just use the disk property as needed for the computer name.  
    # $computer = $computer.toupper() 
        
    foreach ($disk in $disks) {         
        ## Removed because you can simply call the object properties directly.   
        ## $deviceID = $disk.DeviceID 
        ## $volName = $disk.VolumeName 
        [float]$size = $disk.Size 
        [float]$freespace = $disk.FreeSpace  
        $percentFree = [Math]::Round(($freespace / $size) * 100, 2) 

        ## by using /1GB you can automagically convert to Gigabyte values.
        ## replace GB with MB, kB and others for different scale.   
        $sizeGB = $size / 1GB
        $freeSpaceGB = $freespace / 1GB
        $usedSpaceGB = $sizeGB - $freeSpaceGB 

        ## Three possibilities, so a Switch is a little better.  
        ## Especially in the scenario of adding further values, you never know.   
        $Class = switch ($percentFree) {
            { $_ -lt $percentCritcal } { 'Critical'; break }         
            { $_ -lt $percentWarning } { 'Warning' ; break }
            default { $null }
        }

        ## Compiles the $TableRowTemplate with the following values, then sends the results to the Success Stream where it gets added to $HtmlTableRowsArray.   
        $TableRowTemplate -f $disk.SystemName.ToUpper(), $disk.deviceID, $disk.VolumeName, $sizeGB, $usedSpaceGB, $freeSpaceGB, $Class, $percentFree

        ## Tell the user through the terminal about it
        Write-Host -ForegroundColor DarkYellow "$($disk.SystemName.ToUpper()) | $($disk.DeviceID) | percentage free space = $percentFree" 
                
    } 
} 


## Just to let the user know... or whatever you need.  
Write-Host "number of disk with problem is: $($HtmlTableRowArray.Count)"

## Compiles the $HtmlTeplate with the values for the title date, the CSS and the disk rows.   
## because $HtmlTableRowArray is an array, it needs to be converted to a single string through -Join.  
## The resulting string is then set on the report file
$HtmlTemplate -f $titleDate, $css, ($HtmlTableRowArray -join [System.Environment]::NewLine) | Set-Content -Path $DiskReportFile


OLD ANSWER

To start, I suggest you to add the HTML and CSS tags.
Especially because this code is using quite old HTML.
It's much easier to use better CSS for your scope.

Get-WmiObject is obsolete and has been removed from Powershell 6+.
Replace it with Get-CimInstance, it works the same(in this case)

You don't need to escape single quotes ' while encapsuled in double quotes "


here, it took me 3e124^(googol) years in notepad.exe to write this down
(read: triple check it because I didn't bother beyond basic functionality and I have no doubt I used some obsolete HTML properties)
# Set your warning and critical thresholds 
$percentWarning = 90; #wildly increased for testing critical threshold
$percentCritcal = 95; #wildly increased for testing


# REPORT PROPERTIES 
# Path to the report 
$reportPath = 'C:\scripts\diskspace\Report\' 

# Report name 
$reportName = "DiskSpaceRpt_$(Get-Date -Format ddMMyyyy).html" 

# Path and Report name together 
$diskReport = Join-Path -Path $reportPath -ChildPath $reportName 

# Count if any computers have low disk space.  Do not send report if less than 1. 
$i = 0 

# Get computer list to check disk space 
$computers = Get-Content 'C:\scripts\diskspace\servers.txt' 
$datetime = Get-Date -Format 'MM-dd-yyyy_HHmmss' 


$null = New-Item $diskReport -Force

# Cleanup old files.. 
$Daysback = '-7' 
$CurrentDate = Get-Date 
$DateToDelete = $CurrentDate.AddDays($Daysback) 
Get-ChildItem $reportPath | Where-Object { $_.LastWriteTime -lt $DatetoDelete } | Remove-Item 

# Create and write HTML Header of report 
$titleDate = Get-Date -UFormat '%m-%d-%Y - %A' 
$Html = " 
<!doctype html>
<html> 
<head> 
<meta http-equiv='Content-Type' content='text/html; charset=utf-8'> 
<title>DiskSpace Report</title> 
<STYLE TYPE='text/css'> 
tr {
    background-color: #cccccc;
}

td,
th {
    text-align: center;
}

th {
    font-family: Tahoma, sans-serif;
    font-weight: bold;
    color: #003399;
}

th.main{
    font-size: larger;
}

tfoot tr {
    background-color: #ffffff;
}

tfoot tr td:first-child {
    background-color: #FBB917;
}

tfoot tr td:last-child {
    background-color: #ff0000;
}



.NoCenter {
    text-align: unset;
}

.Warning {
    color: #FBB917;
}

.Critical {
    color: #ff0000;
    background-color: #ffffff;
}
</style> 
</head> 
<body> 
<table width='100%'> 
<thead>  
    <tr >
        <th colspan='7' class='main'>   ghostinthewires Internal DiskSpace Report for $titledate  </th>
    </tr>   
    <tr> 
        <th width='10%' >Server</th> 
        <th width='5%' >Drive</th> 
        <th width='15%' >Drive Label</th> 
        <th width='10%' >Total Capacity(GB)</th> 
        <th width='10%' >Used Capacity(GB)</th> 
        <th width='10%' >Free Space(GB)</th> 
        <th width='5%' >Freespace %</th> 
    </tr> 
</thead>
<tbody>
"

$HtmlFooter = "
</tbody> 
<tfoot>
    <tr> 
        <td width='10%'>Warning less than 15% free space</td> 
        <td width='10%'>Critical less than 10% free space</td> 
    </tr> 
</tfoot>
</table>
</body>
</html>
" 

$dataRow = " 
    <tr> 
        <td width='10%'>{0}</td> 
        <td width='5%' >{1}</td> 
        <td width='15%' class='NoCenter'>{2}</td> 
        <td width='10%' >{3:n2}</td> 
        <td width='10%' >{4:n2}</td> 
        <td width='10%' >{5:n2}</td> 
        <td width='5%' class='{6}' >{7}</td> 
    </tr> 
"




# Start processing disk space reports against a list of servers 
foreach ($computer in $computers) {  
    $disks = Get-CimInstance -ComputerName $computer -Class Win32_LogicalDisk -Filter 'DriveType = 3' 
    # $computer = $computer.toupper() 
    foreach ($disk in $disks) {         
        $deviceID = $disk.DeviceID 
        $volName = $disk.VolumeName 
        [float]$size = $disk.Size 
        [float]$freespace = $disk.FreeSpace  
        $percentFree = [Math]::Round(($freespace / $size) * 100, 2) 
        $sizeGB = $size / 1GB
        # $sizeGB.gettype(); pause
        $freeSpaceGB = $freespace / 1GB
        $usedSpaceGB = $sizeGB - $freeSpaceGB 
        $Class = $Null

        # Set background color to Orange if just a warning 
        if ($percentFree -lt $percentWarning) { 
            $Class = '.Warning'

            # Set background color to Orange if space is Critical 
            if ($percentFree -lt $percentCritcal) { 
                $class = '.Critical'
            }         


            $Html += $dataRow -f $computer, $deviceID, $volName, $sizeGB, $usedSpaceGB, $freeSpaceGB, $Class, $percentFree

            
            Write-Host -ForegroundColor DarkYellow "$computer $deviceID percentage free space = $percentFree" 
            $i++   
        } 
    } 
} 

# A table at end of report showing legend of colors for the critical and warning 
$Html += $HtmlFooter

# Export to the file.   
$Html | Set-Content -Path $diskReport


Good answer. I would only suggest pointing out the specific css/style changes you made and how you are programmatically updating the class of the last percentage cell to use them.  Otherwise, bravo :)

Thank you. Getting out of work now, I'll update tomorrow.

@Daniel updated! I think the new version should be compliant with your suggestions :)

Thanks a ton, firing up a VM now to test.

It works - can't thank you enough!

just make sure to add some error management... I haven't bothered to add any and there are a few points where it might be useful

Last one - (may I send you a 6 pack of IPA?) :)

Damn, email handler is not working
What variable will push the content?
$msg.Subject = "Servers DiskSpace Report for $titledate"
$msg.IsBodyHTML = $true
$msg.Body = get-content $DiskReportFile
$smtp.Send($msg)
$body = ""
}
}

Open a new question, that's a whole different issue.
